# Returning variables from within class PHP

Tags: php

I am currently learning object oriented programming to write a custom plugin, and I want to be able to access variables within a class.

For example my class would look like this

```
class GeoSlugArray {

    var $geoslugarray = array (
        'london',
        'manchester'
    );

    static function lnz_wc_memberships_get_geoslugarray() {
        return $this->geoslugarray;
    }
}
```

And I would use it on page / in a function like this:

```
$slugs = GeoSlugArray::lnz_wc_memberships_get_geoslugarray();
print_r($slugs);
```

But this doesn't work I get a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/benefacto/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/bnfo-custom-memberships/includes/class-bnfo-wc-memberships-geoslug.php:28 Stack trace
```

I can get this to work by creating a new instance e.g.

```
$request = new GeoSlugArray();
$slugs = $request->lnz_wc_memberships_get_geoslugarray();
```

But I think that is clunky. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: How about googling your error text? Or you think only you met this error?

Comment: replace `$this->var` with `self::var` when used static

Comment: First `$geoslugarray` will also need to be `public static` (`var` is outdated). You should specify `public static function` too (for clarity). Finally, to actually fix the error, you should `return self::$geoslugarray`.

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol and Jeff much appreciated.

Comment: @u_mulder.... what is this 'Google' thing you speak of?

Comment: `var $geoslugarray` is the PHP/4 syntax, deprecated for something like 13 years. It's the IT equivalent of learning Latin before moving to Italy ;-)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks for the heads up. I was learning OOP from this guide: http://www.killerphp.com/downloads/object-oriented-php/downloads/oop_in_php_tutorial.pdf but will find something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to the solution described in the comments:

```
class GeoSlugArray {

    private static $geoslugarray = array (
        'london',
        'manchester'
    );

    public static function lnz_wc_memberships_get_geoslugarray() {
        return self::$geoslugarray;
    }
}
```

If the array always stays the same (if it is not manipulated programatically), there is also the possibility of using a class constant (with PHP 5.6.0 or newer):

```
class GeoSlugArray {

       const $geoslugarray = array (
            'london',
            'manchester'
        );
}
```

You can access this by using `GeoSlugArray::$geoslugarray` from outside the class or `self::$geoslugarray` from inside the class.

The tutorial you followed seems to be outdated, you should look for a more recent one.

A last little hint: use the camelCase method for variables and functions, this is mostly considered best practise nowadays:
`$geoslugarray` -> `$geoSlugArray`